# Problem with .append(), select lists, and Chrome 81

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

As of Chrome 81 release, pulling options from a select list and re-adding them with `.append()` does not seem to work as expected.  This behavior was working in Chrome 80, and continues to work in other browsers.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Chrome?

**Example code steps**

- get the select list
- get the options from it (in production code I'm manipulating them, but for this example am not)
- remove the options from the list
- re-add the options to the list

**Expected behavior**

list has options

**Actual behavior**

no options shown, though DOM inspector shows that they are present

**Snippet**

```js
function test() {
   var selectItem = $("#selectOne");
   var items = selectItem.find('option');
   selectItem.empty();
   selectItem.append(items);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOne" multiple>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>

<br/>

<button onclick="test()">Go</button>
```

Adding the following line to the end of my javascript does "fix" the problem:

```
selectItem.get(0).innerHTML = selectItem.get(0).innerHTML;
```

However this is clearly not an actual fix.  I only include it here in case it helps someone who understands this more than I do to pinpoint the problem.

EDIT 21 April: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1073172 (thanks to whomever opened this!)

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue, but I'm not really sure what's causing it, the way I see it working it's using `.clone()` after your `find`

Comment: I don't follow.  If I add a `.clone()` after the `find` it works the same way (meaning, it still does not work).

Comment: it renders the elements after with that , so it looks likes this `.find("option").clone()`

Comment: On mac, it appears to render when unfocusing chrome / selecting another system window. Definitely seems like a bug.

Comment: Yep, it was confirmed as a bug and should be fixed in Chrome 84 (or possibly 83).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone your `option`'s , by doing that it will render the options again,

this it's the only line that you need to change

```
var items = selectItem.find('option');
```

to this

```
var items = selectItem.find('option').clone();
```

```js
function test() {
   var selectItem = $("#selectOne");
   var items = selectItem.find('option').clone();
   selectItem.empty();
   selectItem.append(items);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectOne" multiple>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>

<br/>

<button onclick="test()">Go</button>
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct that this fixes the issue, but I'm concerned that this is an undocumented, and possibly unintended, change to the Chrome JavaScript processor.  I can't find anything in the release notes about this change.

Comment: Agree with @trebla that this does appear to work, though I am similarly worried about the regression in Chrome.  This is also not ideal (performance, memory) for select lists with thousands of elements but to be fair those aren't especially ideal in the first place.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: We're seeing this in Chome 81 as well. Has anyone found an existing issue on the Chromium issue tracker?

Comment: @Trebla reported it via Chrome's help menu, but I do not know where those end up or if they have to make it through some review process first.

Comment: FYI updated original post with link to chromium issue.  I didn't submit that, so I'm guessing you did...if so, then thanks!

Comment: Indeed, but it was just closed as a duplicate of https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072475. Definitely a regression.